# Duplicating elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a reusable form script for my organization. One feature is to duplicate form elements. For this instance, I ask for date of event, but have the option to add a day to the event.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Date of event<sup>*</sup></label>
        <input class="field-required" type="text" name="event_date" readonly="readonly" />
    </li>           
    <li>
        <ul class="float-fields">
            <li>
                <label>Start time<sup>*</sup></label>
                <input class="field-required" type="text" name="event_start_time" data-validation="time" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>End time<sup>*</sup></label>
                <input class="field-required" type="text" name="event_end_time" data-validation="time" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <a class="duplicate-fields" data-fields="all">&plus; Add date</a>
</ul>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
    //duplicate fields
    $('.duplicate-fields').each(function() {

        //put fields in a variable
        if($(this).attr('data-fields') == 'all') {
            var html = $(this).parent('ul').html();
        }

        $(this).click(function() {
            $($(this).parent('ul')).append(html);
        })

    });
```

What this does right now is duplicate the html of the ul (all of the li's) and append it, as you would expect. What I need to do is exclude the '.duplicate-fields' link, so that the link is not repeated, and insert the li's above the existing link.

I like what .clone() can do, but I need for this to be in a variable so that I can duplicate the fields for an indefinite number. With clone, I can say:

```
var html = $(this).parent('ul').clone();
$(html).find('.duplicate-fields').remove();
```

But from what I understand, If I use clone(), I can only duplicate once.
Any suggestions on how I should do this? This is reusable, as only the HTML should have to be edited for future use (no special classes or id's).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, based off of User3013738's answer.

```
    //duplicate fields
    var html = '';
    $('.duplicate-fields').each(function() {
        //put fields in a variable
        if($(this).attr('data-fields') == 'all') {
            $(this).parent('ul').find('li:not(li li)').each(function() {
                html += '<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>';
            });
        }

        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).before(html);
        })

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to *iterate the clone using a for loop.*

**updated code:**

```
 $('.duplicate-fields').each(function () {
     if ($(this).attr('data-fields') == 'all') {
         var noOfClones = 5;
         var el = $(this).parent();
         for (var i = 0; i < noOfClones; i++) {
             var html = el.clone();
             html.appendTo('body');            
         }
     }
 });
```

Finally, when `a` tag is being clicked

```
$(document).on('click', '.duplicate-fields', function () {
    var noOfClones = 5;  //you can change it to repeatitve times
    var el = $(this).parent();
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfClones; i++) {
        var html = el.clone();
        html.find('a.duplicate-fields').remove(); //remove the a tag in cloned objects
        html.appendTo('body'); //append back
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/nqxr6/3/)

Comment: Do you really need to fetch the html in every iteration?

Comment: `$(html)` should just be `html`, because `el.clone()` already returns a jQuery object. (While we're on it, `html` is probably a bad name for this var as it is a jQuery object not a string of HTML... but that's just opinion)

Comment: For me, this only duplicated the link, and appends to the link. I need for it to duplicated the html of my parent ul, and insert above the link.

Comment: This is how I understood your answer:
`//duplicate fields
  $('.duplicate-fields').each(function() {

   var noOfClones = 5;
   var el = $(this).parent('ul');
   for (var i=0; i<noOfClones; i++) {
    var html = el.clone();
   }
   
   $(this).click(function() {
    $(html).find('.duplicate-fields').remove().appendTo('.duplicate-fields');
   });

  });`

Comment: `$(this).click(function() {
    $(html).find('.duplicate-fields').remove();
    $(html).appendTo(el);
   });`

Still what I had before, only works once, and it add is beneath the link.

Comment: @nitsuj This is what is tried to mention `$('.duplicate-fields').each(function () {

     //put fields in a variable
     if ($(this).attr('data-fields') == 'all') {
         var noOfClones =5;
         var el = $(this).parent();         
         for (var i = 0; i < noOfClones; i++) {
             var html = el.clone();
             html.remove('.duplicate-fields').appendTo('body');
         }         
     }
 });`

Comment: @nitsuj check this fiddle,http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/nqxr6/1/.  let me know if you have any problem

Comment: So this repeats it 5 times in your fiddle. I need to be able to repeat this for an indefinite number of times, but only when the link is clicked.

Comment: @nitsuj I have given you the gist of how to do.  But you expected me to do(though I love to try).  When you search for answer, practice it.  Check my updated answer and its fiddle.  Hope you understand, now you can try different approach.

Comment: I do not expect for you to do it. I need a specific solution, and assuming that you're the expert on this particular issue, I try what you suggest, which gives results contrary to what I requested.

Your update fiddle still adds 5, but I can change that variable to 1 and almost get what I want. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `var noOfClones = 5;` here you can set the number of clones that you need.  are you trying to do infinite times?

Comment: Yes. The user should be able to add as many days (in this instance) as he or she requires. Also, this adds it to the body. When I change to add to the parent 'ul', the next time that I try to duplicate, it duplicates the duplicate too. Hm...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
//duplicate fields
$('.duplicate-fields').each(function() {
    //put fields in a variable
    if($(this).attr('data-fields') == 'all') {
        var html = $(this).parent('ul').find('li:not(:has(ul.float-fields))').html(); 
        html += $(this).parent('ul').find('li:has(ul.float-fields)').html();
    }

    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).before(html);
    })

});
```

Comment: Okay, I'm looking at this. You might be on to something.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. See my answer, based off of yours.